# chrome app make it legacy app

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How to make my app legacy app, so i can use `options_page` option in it?

I have angular app, and i made it to run in chrome app, and everything works, but i need to have options page, so i can setup some variables.

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "description": "Descrription",
  "version": "0.5",
  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/images/icons/16x16.png",
    "48": "assets/images/icons/48x48.png",
    "128": "assets/images/icons/128x128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "http://*/"
  ]
}
```

I get warning that i can't use options in packaged app..

Comment: The new options page doesn't seem all that different from the existing: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2 .  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Teepeemm The link you sent is for a future version of Chrome. The problem here is that Chrome Apps don't allow for an options link in the context menu of the app list (so your link does not apply at all), unlike legacy packaged apps. But, as I mentioned in my answer, legacy packaged apps are deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you [strongly should not](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/06/migrate-your-legacy-packaged-apps-to.html). Legacy apps are called so for a reason: they are no longer supported. You will not be able to publish such an app, and they will stop working altogether at a later date.

However, your approach is kind of wrong. A Chrome App is supposed to be self-contained, with its options merged into its interface. You shouldn't look to have the options link buried somewhere in Chrome, you should display the options interface in your app's UI.

Comment: That's not bad solution, but can i make it to open as new window, or should i do something like bootstrap modal? Any example?

Comment: You have two options; if you want to keep UI in a single window, then something like a modal will works will. If you think a separate window will serve better, you can call `chrome.app.window.create` from the main UI.

Comment: @MirzaDelic Er, what kind of example? Just bind `chrome.app.window.create("options.html")` to a click on some element. Optionally set things like window size in optional parameters.